# Bootstrap 4's '.carousel-indicators' are cycling but won't go to its item when you click them

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I did as what the docs snippet did.

```
<div id="#myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="car-btn active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="car-btn"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="car-btn"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3" class="car-btn"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item item active">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/home/slider-1/1-medium.jpg'); ?>" alt="Slide - 01">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/home/slider-1/2-medium.jpg'); ?>" alt="Slide - 02">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/home/slider-1/3-medium.jpg'); ?>" alt="Slide - 03">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/home/slider-1/4-medium.jpg'); ?>" alt="Slide - 04">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" style="display:none;">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" style="display:none;">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

With the javascript:

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 4000,
    pause: false,
    wrap: true
 });
```

The carousel works, it slides automatically, but nothing happens when you click on the indicators, though it does change classes to active when the image change. I'm hiding them, but the `prev` and `next` also are not working.

**UPDATE:**
I even tried manually firing it, but still nothing:

```
    $('.car-btn').click(function(){
        var slideTo = $(this).attr('data-slide-to');
        $('#myCarousel').carousel(slideTo);
    });
```

Comment: Remove the # from the id you have given.

Comment: @Saurav *facepalm* how stupid of me